# Modify xml uttribut value of an xml document by selector

Tags: command-line, utilities, xml, text-formatting

I have an xml document containing an element witch I can select with `stkconfig>Video[width]`. So, I want to modify the value of this element.

There is a CLI utilities for this?

Comment: Several.  The one to try first is probably [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: see other xmlstarlet questions in the [tag:xmlstarlet] tag page and on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find [XML Starlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) as suggested by Sato.

I use for that `xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "/stkconfig/Video/@width" -v <new value> <path to my document`.